# PrimeReact custom paginator template rendering for LastPageLink

Tags: reactjs, pagination, paginator, primereact

I am trying to Customly render paginator that will be a kind of like this 1 2 3 ... 10/ 1...8 9 10 / 1 ..3 4 5..10 depends on the current page. how I can render this for my primereact datatable paginator? I am trying to using lastPageLinks for rendering 10 the end page. but I don't have a totalpages count like pagelinks. here 10 is the total page number

I try to call the custom template by totalpages number it works for the lazyload but don't work if lazyload is false. I want to use state in side of the custom template to get totalpage from pagelinks and use it in LastPagelink but console give error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: even better would be a StackBlitz reproducer showing the problem you have so we can debug an MVCE.